# Paypal IPN Help. Sending file attachments through email

Tags: php, email, pdf, paypal

I don't know much about PHP. I hired a freelancer to create this for me and then after I noticed an issue, his account was closed on freelancer.com. So I'm no longer able to communicate with him. So any help is greatly appreciate. He created a system for me that automatically emails digital files to an eBay customer. It used the quantity and price information from PayPal IPN to do this. All of my digital files are one time use. So once a file is purchased on eBay, it gets emailed to the customer and then discarded. The system works great when a customer orders a quantity of 1.

The issue is when the customer orders more than 1. 2 scenarios happen: For example if a customer orders 2 digital files, lets says "XB1.pdf" and "XB2.pdf". Scenario 1 they will get "XB1.pdf" in an email and sometimes get "XB2.pdf" in a second email, but the email is filled with a bunch of giberish (I posted the email contents to the bottom of the ipn.php contents below). Scenario 2 sometimes they will get 2 emails but both contain "XB1.pdf" only and not "XB2.pdf". Can you look at the code and see if you can spot the issue? This is the ipn.php file contents and i believe this is where the issue is.

**ipn.ph contents**

```
<?php namespace Listener;

include('config.php');

// Set this to true to use the sandbox endpoint during testing:
$enable_sandbox = true;

// Set this to true to send a confirmation email:
$send_confirmation_email = true;




require('PaypalIPN.php');
use PaypalIPN;
$ipn = new PaypalIPN();
if ($enable_sandbox) {
    $ipn->useSandbox();
}
$verified = $ipn->verifyIPN();
$no_of_items=1;
$data_text = "";
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    $data_text .= $key . " = " . $value . "\r\n";
    if($key == "quantity"){
    $no_of_items=$value;
    }
    if($key == "payment_gross"){
    $total_payment=$value;  
    }
    if($key == "payer_email"){
    $payer_email=$value;    
    }
    if($key == "payment_status"){
    $payment_status=$value; 
    }

}
mail("", "sub", $data_text);


if ($send_confirmation_email) {
    // Send confirmation email
$total_payment=$total_payment/$no_of_items;

mail("", "total_payment", $total_payment);

$sql_s = "select * from settings";
$result_s = $conn->query($sql_s);
if ($result_s->num_rows > 0) {
while($query2_s = $result_s->fetch_assoc()) {

$email_from=$query2_s['email_from'];    
$email_subject=$query2_s['email_subject'];
$email_toa=$query2_s['email_to'];
$email_message=$query2_s['email_message'];
//$fileatt_name=$query2_s['fileame'];
$mail_me=$query2_s['mail_me'];  
}}

mail("", "no_of_items", $no_of_items);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM coupons where price='$total_payment' AND status=0 OR status=2 LIMIT ".$no_of_items."";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

$status=$row['status'];     
if($status == 0 || $status == 2){
$file=$row['file']; 
$fileatt_name=$file;
$id=$row['id'];     
$fileatt = "files/".$file;
mail("", "file", $file);

            $fileatt_type = "application/pdf";
            $email_to =  $payer_email;
            $headers = "From: ".$email_from;
            $file = fopen($fileatt,'rb');
            $data = fread($file,filesize($fileatt));
            fclose($file);
            $semi_rand = md5(time());
            $mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x";
            $headers .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n" .
            "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n" .
            " boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\"";
            $email_message .= "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n\n" .
            "--{$mime_boundary}\n" .
            "Content-Type:text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n" .
            "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" .
            $email_message .= "\n\n";
            $data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));
            $email_message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n" .
            "Content-Type: {$fileatt_type};\n" .
            " name=\"{$fileatt_name}\"\n" .
            "Content-Disposition: attachment;\n" .
            " filename=\"{$fileatt_name}\"\n" .
            //"Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" .
            $data .= "\n\n" . "--{$mime_boundary}--\n";
            $ok = @mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);
            if($email_toa != ""){
            $oka = @mail($email_toa, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);
            }

if($status == 0){
$sql = "UPDATE coupons SET status='1',sent_to='$payer_email' WHERE id='$id'";
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {}
}else if($status == 2){
if($row['sent_to'] != ""){  
$payer_email=$row['sent_to'].",".$payer_email;
}
$sql = "UPDATE coupons SET sent_to='$payer_email' WHERE id='$id'";
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {}

}


}}}else {   
$oka = @mail($mail_me, "No File Found", "HI,<br>".$payer_email." has made a payment of ".$total_payment." but coupon could not be found.");


    }


}

// Reply with an empty 200 response to indicate to paypal the IPN was received correctly
header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
```

**trash email contents, this is only a portion of it since it is very long**

> Write anything you want here. This will be the body of the email that
>   is sent. This is a multi-part message in MIME format.
>   --==Multipart_Boundary_xad2df9824fad4231989b39a4240b752ex Content-Type:text/html; charset="iso-8859-1"
>   Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit Write anything you want here. This
>   will be the body of the email that is sent.
>   --==Multipart_Boundary_xad2df9824fad4231989b39a4240b752ex Content-Type: application/pdf; name="566222_XL-48Hour_3.pdf"
>   Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="566222_XL-48Hour_3.pdf"
>   JVBERi0xLjUNCiW1tbW1DQoxIDAgb2JqDQo8PC9UeXBlL0NhdGFsb2cvUGFnZXMgMiAwIFIvTGFu
>   Zyhlbi1VUykgL1N0cnVjdFRyZWVSb290IDEyIDAgUi9NYXJrSW5mbzw8L01hcmtlZCB0cnVlPj4+
>   Pg0KZW5kb2JqDQoyIDAgb2JqDQo8PC9UeXBlL1BhZ2VzL0NvdW50IDEvS2lkc1sgMyAwIFJdID4+
>   DQplbmRvYmoNCjMgMCBvYmoNCjw8L1R5cGUvUGFnZS9QYXJlbnQgMiAwIFIvUmVzb3VyY2VzPDwv
>   Rm9udDw8L0YxIDUgMCBSL0YyIDkgMCBSPj4vRXh0R1N0YXRlPDwvR1M3IDcgMCBSL0dTOCA4IDAg
>   Uj4+L1Byb2NTZXRbL1BERi9UZXh0L0ltYWdlQi9JbWFnZUMvSW1hZ2VJXSA+Pi9NZWRpYUJveFsg
>   MCAwIDYxMiA3OTJdIC9Db250ZW50cyA0IDAgUi9Hcm91cDw8L1R5cGUvR3JvdXAvUy9UcmFuc3Bh
>   cmVuY3kvQ1MvRGV2aWNlUkdCPj4vVGFicy9TL1N0cnVjdFBhcmVudHMgMD4+DQplbmRvYmoNCjQg
>   MCBvYmoNCjw8L0ZpbHRlci9GbGF0ZURlY29kZS9MZW5ndGggMTc1Nz4+DQpzdHJlYW0NCniclVht
>   b5tIEP4eKf9h++UEp8uGXXYXqKpKbdKmOTXXKPFVkar7QGzsoNjGApzU//5mBkjA9bprVW0NzM7r

Comment: Is the code really formatted like that, or did it get messed up somehow when posted here on SO?

Comment: I updated it, the ipn.php contents should look better now

Comment: There are a few lines like `mail("", "total_payment", $total_payment);` - are they really like that, or have you removed an email address?

Comment: Oh sorry, yes i temporarily removed the email addresses. Those were used for checking purposes im assuming.

Comment: If need be I can send all the php files

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the code is appending to `$email_message` on each loop.  First time through that is fine; 2nd time through a new set of headings and data is appended to the original email message, which breaks things.

To see the problem in more detail, follow through the code.  This line sets the initial content of the msg:

```
$email_message = $query2_s['email_message'];
```

The content comes from the database, and from the output you've included we can see it is:

> Write anything you want here. This will be the body of the email that is sent.

Next, the code selects records to be processed, and starts to iterate over them.  It constructs the message by appending some data to the existing content prepared above:

```
$email_message .= "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n\n"
// etc, there are several lines of headers added here
```

Finally, the mail is sent, using the content constructed in the last few steps:

```
$ok = @mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);
```

All good, the content of this first mail is fine.  However, if there was more than one item, the code now loops and runs a second time for the next record.  And here's the problem - `$email_message` is not reset back to an empty string, or the initial "Write anything you want ..." msg from the database.  Instead a second set of headers are added to the existing message content:

```
$email_message .= "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n\n"
// etc, appends new stuff to existing $email_message
```

`$email_message` now includes headers and content for mail 1, with headers and content for mail 2 appended to it.

To avoid this, use different variable names.  Eg instead of this line:

```
$email_message = $query2_s['email_message'];
```

Use:

```
$email_prefix = $query2_s['email_message'];
```

Then instead of:

```
$email_message .= "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n\n" .
```

Use:

```
$email_message = $email_prefix . "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n\n" .
```

This way `$email_message` is created from scratch on each iteration, using the `$email_prefix` from the database and appending the rest of the msg.

Comment: Still having the same issue. Thank you so much for the help though. I might have to hire a freelancer to fix the code of the previous freelancer. Or maybe Ill just have to learn php lol

Comment: @RLane Are you getting exactly the same problem, with garbage in the message, and the doubled "Write anything you want ..."?  If so, something went wrong with the edits, as what I describe will fix that.  If you're seeing some other error, there might be *another* problem in the code related to multiple items.

Comment: Now just 1 email with 1 file is getting sent no matter how many emailed. I updated the 2 lines you mentioned above. I also removed the // from the lines that were commented out. Im not sure why the programmer commented them out.

Comment: It's fixed now. Thank you so much for your help. It now works as it should. The freelancer finally got back to me :)